# Artin vanishing for Stein manifolds and restriction maps

Tags: cohomology, complex-manifolds, morse-theory, derham-cohomology, stein-manifolds

In the setting of complex Stein manifolds $X$ of complex dimension $d$, the theorem of Andreotti--Frankel implies the vanishing of the singular cohomology group $H^i(X,\mathbb Z)=0$ for $i>d$. With complex coefficients, a simple argument for this is to compute the cohomology in terms of the cohomology of the de Rham complex. Their theorem gives a more precise Morse-theoretic statement.

Now let $U\subset X$ be another Stein manifold open in $X$, and assume that the map $\mathcal O(X)\to \mathcal O(U)$ has dense image. (This condition is not automatic, and necessary for the following.)

> Conjecture. In top degree, the map $H^d(X,\mathbb Z)\to H^d(U,\mathbb Z)$ is surjective.

Is this known? The same result should also be true with constructible coefficients. With $\mathbb C$-coefficients, it follows from the comparison with de Rham cohomology (at least when cohomology groups are finite-dimensional, which I'm happy to assume). Is there some argument using Morse theory?

The motivation for the question is that the analogue in rigid-analytic geometry is true (but I found it quite surprising); it is essentially equivalent to a version of Artin vanishing for affine schemes over absolutely integrally closed valuation rings stated by Gabber in Oberwolfach last year.

Comment: Is there an easy argument for smooth affine algebraic varieties?

Comment: Shouldn't the closed complement of an open Stein submanifold of a (connected) Stein manifold be "generically" a hypersurface in the ambient Stein manifold?  If so, it seems impossible to have the "dense image" condition, unless the open equals the entire ambient manifold or the empty set, i.e., the two cases where the conjecture is trivially true.

Comment: @JasonStarr An example would be a small open ball inside affine space

Comment: @virkkunen If both $U$ and $X$ are affine algebraic, the hypothesis is basically never satisfied (as Jason Starr observed). But you are welcome to assume that $X$ is an affine algebraic variety.

Comment: What topology are you using?  For the open unit disk in the complex plane, the holomorphic restriction of $1/(1-z)$ is certainly not approximated by restrictions of entire holomorphic functions in the uniform topology (since these are bounded on the closure of the disk).

Comment: I'm using the Frechet topology on $\mathcal O(X)$ and $\mathcal O(U)$ (of uniform convergence on compact subsets), as I believe is the standard choice. (Sorry for not specifying.)

Comment: Interesting question. The inclusion of $\mathbb{C}^*\subset \mathbb{C}$ is an open immersion of Stein manifolds where the map on $H^d$ is not surjective, but I'm not sure about the density condition for function spaces.

Comment: It doesn't have dense image: One argument is to observe that the residue at $0$ of a function on $\mathbb C^\times$ gives a nonzero continuous functional which vanishes on the image of $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb C)$. The same argument applies more generally to hyperplane complements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pairs (U,X) are called Runge pairs. The homology version of your statement is proved in the paper of
Andreotti and Narasimhan Annals of Math vol 76 no 3 (1962) 499-509 using Morse
Theory.The title of the paper is "A Topological property of Runge pairs"
The paper by Coltoiu Mihalache titled On the Homology Groups of Stein spaces and Runge pairs, Journal fur reine und angewandte Mathematik volume 371 no 5 pages 215-220 proves the homology statement for Runge pairs of Stein spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these references! (Is the version with constructible coefficients also known?)

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Comment: I don't think the case of constructible coefficients is known but I am not sure.